# Woocommerce : Replace ' Product Categories ' by ' Short Description ' on Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

In the product page, each product has an image, and below two sub caption : the title and a link to the product categories. I'd like to replace this product categories field with the short description of the product.

I had a look at every php file in the woocomerce folder, but can't find the line to edit.

thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in WooCommerce, It is located in `wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > templates > single-product > meta.php` **Line 30**

But if you are using themes for woocommerce, then it might be located at some other place but for that you need to debug by your self to find it.

**NOTE :** DO NOT change the default WooCommerce file directly. There is nice [tutorial](http://www.woothemes.com/2014/08/five-quick-woocommerce-customization-tips/) about it.

**EDITED**

Replace it with below code:

```
<?php
   global $post;
   if ( ! $post->post_excerpt ) {
       return;
   }
?>
<div itemprop="description">
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thank so much for the quick answer ! I found the line. Wich code should I add to add the short description ? something like echo excerpt I guess ?

Comment: thanks. I just tried with the code but nothing happen. Maybe as you said the line to edit is in the theme himself. The theme is neighbordhood.

Comment: You can check it by going to your theme's folder : `wp-content > themes > yourtheme > woocommerce > single-product > meta.php` In that file is there product category ? I can not check it as it is not freeware.

Comment: the page is http://bicycleshopkits.com/product-category/bicycle-stands/ : I try to replace  " Bicycle Stand " with each product short description. ( obviously I wanna do that for every product page )

Comment: You can upvote it or even accept my answer. Glad that I can help you.